# Can someone explain me the Syntax of a loop like "for (;;)"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, expression, statements, ecmascript-2020

Can someone explain me the Syntax of a `for-loop` like ***`"for (;;)"`*** what i need to know is whether the header of a `for-loop` like ***`"for (;;)"`*** is having ***`empty-statements`*** or not.

I searched the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iteration-statements) about what will happen if all the optional expressions within the `for-loop's` header is skipped like ***`for (;;)`*** in the specification but i still didnt find about it

can someone explain me about this even the specification haven't mentioned that a `for-loop` like `for (;;)` loops/runs infinite times

and i need to know one last thing why people call the header of a `for-loop` is having `Expression's` i see that the syntax of a for loop allows us to write declarations like `var i = 0` `in the header of the for-loop` and i see the `for-loops` syntax allows us to write `semicolons ;` in its header only statements require `semicolons` does that mean all the syntax within the `for-loop's` header is having `Statements`

Comment: The [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) is quite clear. In general, programming documentation will put items in brackets `[]` when that item is optional.

Comment: An "empty" `for` runs forever because the abort condition is only evaluated when there is one. No condition to check -> No reason to stop. It's defined here [13.7.4.8 Runtime Semantics: ForBodyEvaluation ( test, increment, stmt, perIterationBindings, labelSet )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-forbodyevaluation)

Comment: *does that mean all the syntax within the for-loop's header is having Statements* Yes. Declarations are expressions, statements are expressions, anything that needs to be evaluated is an expression.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i dont think declarartions are `Expressions`

Comment: @Kevin Technically true. But, all declarations include expressions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus No, _Statements_ include expressions. _Declaration_ are exactly everything that are not _Statements_. See [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-StatementListItem).

Comment: @user4642212 What is on the right-hand side of the equal sign here: `let x = y++;`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus The word “include” is ambiguous. What I meant by _“Statements include expressions”_ is that `Expression` is a valid stand-alone, non-terminal symbol produced from `Statement` in the formal grammar defined by the spec. Of course, both statements and declarations can include `Expression`s _somewhere_ in them, but an `Expression` _alone_ is not a `Declaration`. `let x = y++;` is a `Declaration` → `LexicalDeclaration` → `LetOrConst` `BindingList` **`;`** → **`let`** `LexicalBinding` **`;`** … etc. This will never resolve to _just_ `Expression` or even _just_ `AssignmentExpression`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus At any rate, _“Declarations are expressions”_ is wrong: `let x;` is not an expression. _“all declarations include expressions”_ is wrong: the class declaration `class A {}` includes 0 expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a standard for loop definition, it would go as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

   //Do something here

}
```

You have your *statement* being defining i as 0 (`var i = 0`). Then, there is the *condition/expression* that the for loop checks each time as it runs, which in this example checks that i is less than 5 (`i < 5`).

So, to address the first part of your question, when you define a for loop as `for(;;)`, you are simply defining a loop with no condition that must be met. Therefore, it continues to run/loop forever. This can be done because all parts of the for loop definition are optional. So, there are no "`empty-statements`". It is simply defining the for loop without the optional arguments. We fill it in with semicolons instead in order to represent the transition between the empty arguments.

Comment: when a `for-loop` is written like `for (;;)` does that mean the for-loop's header is having all `empty-statements`

Comment: There's no "empty-statement". There is in fact nothing at all. All three parts of the header are optional.

Comment: Andreas, with further thinking, I agree. I mean you could just call it an empty statement, but that isn't really what is happening since all parameters are optional.

Comment: @Andreas you should read this ["empty-statement"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty)

Comment: @dguis though all the parameter's of a for-loop's header is optional we will have to write `semicolons ;` in the `for-loop's` header which is not optional

Comment: @Kevin The semicolons simply show that we are not passing in any values for the arguments. They are not the arguments themselves.

Comment: @dguis so you mean both the `semicolons ;` within the header of the `for-loop` `for (; ;)` are not `empty statements`

Comment: @user4642212 thats right but do you know why the ECMAScript specification states that the header of the `for-loop` contains `Expressions`

Comment: @Kevin That’s because the second and third part of a `for` loop head are always expressions (condition, and post-iteration). Only the first one can be a non-expression statement (limited to variable declarations). There are [multiple production rules for a `for` loop](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-for-statement), which make the first part either a `var`, or a `const` or `let` declaration, or any expression. You’re right though, that these aren’t empty statements. All three parts can simply be made _optional_ (due to the `opt` next to each part). The semicolons aren’t optional, though.

Comment: @user4642212 i guess that the second part of the `for-loop` header is an `Expression statement (THE CONDITION)` [ExpressionStatement](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionStatement) because there's a semicolon after the `expression (THE CONDITION)` but the last part in the `for-loop's header (THE POST-ITERATION)`  is just an `expression` because there is no semicolon after it

Comment: @Kevin No, the semicolons are part of the `for` statement production itself, _not_ part of the _Expression_ productions within any `for` statement production. Else, you could do `for(let i = 0; i < 9; ; ++i);` which is not valid.